# Data Frame - Fill in Missing Data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with a date, a group (factor) and value column.

```
   Date       Group       Value
01/01/2015      A           1
01/01/2015      B           5
01/01/2015      C           4
01/02/2015      A           10
01/02/2015      B           1
01/03/2015      C           5
```

Some of the groups do not have values entered for the dates. In the above example Group C does not have a value for 01/02/2015. A & B do not have values for 01/03/2015.

I would like to fill in these missing rows with values of zero, like this (order is not important):

```
Date           Group    Value
01/01/2015       A        1
01/01/2015       B        5
01/01/2015       C        4
01/02/2015       A        10
01/02/2015       B        1
01/03/2015       C        5
01/03/2015       A        0
01/03/2015       B        0
01/02/2015       C        0
```

Does anyone know of an easy way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one-liner.  It converts the data from long form to wide form and then back to long form.  No packages are used.

```
as.data.frame(xtabs(Value ~ Group + Date, DF), responseName = "Value")
```

giving:

```
  Group       Date Value
1     A 01/01/2015     1
2     B 01/01/2015     5
3     C 01/01/2015     4
4     A 01/02/2015    10
5     B 01/02/2015     1
6     C 01/02/2015     0
7     A 01/03/2015     0
8     B 01/03/2015     0
9     C 01/03/2015     5
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "Date   Group       Value
01/01/2015      A           1
01/01/2015      B           5
01/01/2015      C           4
01/02/2015      A           10
01/02/2015      B           1
01/03/2015      C           5"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Bingo, worked perfectly. A simple and elegant solution. Much appreciated! I'm getting an error when trying to accept the answer so will try again later.